# pandas multiindex assignment complex broadcasting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multiindex that looks like this:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a", "b"], ["p", "q"], ["x", "y"]])

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=list("ABCD"))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
         A    B    C    D
a p x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  q x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
b p x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  q x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I would like to broadcast an assignment of the value `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]` to the location `"a"` at level 0, and `["x", "y"]` at level 2, and all locations for level 1. So the resulting dataframe would like this:

```
         A    B    C    D
a p x    1    2    3    4
    y    5    6    7    8
  q x    1    2    3    4
    y    5    6    7    8
b p x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  q x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Is this possible in a single assignment operation? My best try has been this, but it doesn't work because the shapes aren't compatible:

```py
In [5]: df.loc["a",:,["x","y"]] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <module>
----> 1 df.loc["a",:,["x","y"]] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4) into shape (4,4)
```

The best I've been able to come up with is doing it in two steps:

```
In [6]: df.loc["a",:,"x"] = [1,2,3,4]

In [7]: df.loc["a",:,"y"] =[5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: I guess it's a bit cheating but how about this: `df.loc['a'] = np.tile([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], (df.index.get_level_values(1).nunique(), 1))`

Comment: @enke I agree it feels a bit cheating, but it's not too bad!

Answer (score 1):

Well after posting this I figured it out on my own. Feeling a bit dumb, but here is a way that works fine:

```py
In [16]: df.loc["a"] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]*2
```

To make it a bit more general:

```
In [20]: expand=len(df.index.levels[-2])

In [21]: df.loc["a"] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]*expand
```

I'd still like to find a nicer way, but this is ok.